# Changing intervals of a function

Tags: functions

When the intervals changed in the function rule  to $(-\pi,0)$ why did $2\pi-x$ become $-x$?

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & 0\le x \le \pi\\ 2\pi-x & \pi < x < 2\pi \end{cases}$$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & 0\le x \le \pi\\ -x & -\pi < x < 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: $(2\pi-x)-2\pi=-x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what you have is incorrect. The original function is not defined for $x$ outside $[0, 2 \pi)$. However, if you are talking about extending the function periodically, then we need $$f(x+2\pi) = f(x)$$
Hence, for $x \in (-\pi,0)$, we want $f(x) = (x+2 \pi)$, where $x+2\pi \in(\pi,2\pi)$, which by definition equals $2 \pi - (x+2 \pi) = -x$. Hence, we get
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x & \text{if }x \in [0, \pi]\\ -x & \text{if }x \in(-\pi,0) \end{cases}$$